# Commit in github repo branch

Tags: netbeans, github

I finished coding a website in my local computer. Now need upload it to one branch github repo. like https://github.com/xxxx/test.git  branch 001

Can you tell me how to commit it in the repo branch

I have already create a local repo commit all files into it by Netbeans. So How can i push the local repo to remote repo branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you locally create a branch Git automatically takes care of creating a new branch on the remote server. Just normally do

> git push

It will create the branch on the remote server.